# make element visible for click in html css

Tags: html, css

I have an element (the green color in image)

[image: screenshot in inspect element]

it has a property

```
top:-5vw;
```

Because of this it covers the link in text (1.5% /year) and makes it unclickable.

How do I make it clickable without replacing anything?
I tried using z-index, but that does not work.

Image is of inspect element, so blue colour is region of 2nd element

Comment: could you please share code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `pointer-events: none;` on div or use negative z-index like `z-index:-1`.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is what you are looking for.
 Z-index has certain things that stop it from acting the way you want it to. common mistakes are setting the position. make sure your positions are not set to static or absolute